# Store comma separated key value pair into table in ORACLE PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to store the key value pair which is like:

```
 TaskType: SRC_Copay,
 [BILLING_ACCOUNT_NUMBER]: 3124332,
 [TOTAL_DESKTOP_COST]: 11423.1,
 [TOTAL_WALKOUT_COST]: 5477.93,
 STATUS: New Sundry Request,
```

Requestor:

I want this to be saved into a table as:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| TaskType | SRC_Copay |

Like: key in separate column as key and value in separate column as data.

How can I do this? Please help

Comment: You can use the `connect by` clause

Comment: I have used CONNECT BY as: SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT ADDITIONAL_INFO FROM TASK_ADDITIONAL_INFO WHERE TASKID = 39308),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) ADDITIONAL_INFO
FROM TASK_ADDITIONAL_INFO
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT ADDITIONAL_INFO FROM TASK_ADDITIONAL_INFO WHERE TASKID = 39308), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL);

but I am getting the value as : TaskType: SRC_Copay
"[BILLING_ACCOUNT_NUMBER]: 3132807
"
"[TOTAL_DESKTOP_COST]: 
"
"[TOTAL_WALKOUT_COST]: 3269.94
"
"STATUS: New Sundry Request
"

Comment: Is each of those name/value pairs in a separate row, or is the whole thing one long text string containing multiple values?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Its in one single string

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `PLSQL` that solves what you are looking for.

- A type to store the record
- A type to store the table
- A pipelined table function to recover the rows split by key value

So the code for the demo

```
SQL> create table t1 ( c1 clob ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1
with tab1 as (
select ' TaskType: SRC_Copay,
 [BILLING_ACCOUNT_NUMBER]: 3124332,
 [TOTAL_DESKTOP_COST]: 11423.1,
 [TOTAL_WALKOUT_COST]: 5477.93,
 STATUS: New Sundry Request,' str
  from dual
 ) select * from tab1 ;  

1 row created.

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 C1                                                 CLOB
```

Now, we create the types and the pipelined function

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT ( key varchar2(100), value varchar2(100) );
/  2

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
/  2

Type created.

SQL> create or replace function split_clob RETURN t_tf_tab PIPELINED 
as
begin
    for h in 
    (
    select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(to_char(t1.c1), '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^:]+', 1, 1) key,
           regexp_substr(regexp_substr(to_char(t1.c1), '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^:]+', 1, 2) value
    from t1
    connect by level < regexp_count(t1.c1, ',') + 1
    and prior rowid = rowid and prior sys_guid() is not null
    )
    loop
        PIPE ROW(t_tf_row(h.key,h.value));   
    end loop;
end;
/

Function created.
```

Let's query the pipelined function

```
SQL> set lines 200 pages 0
SQL> col key for a40
SQL> select key from table(split_clob())
 TaskType
 [BILLING_ACCOUNT_NUMBER]
 [TOTAL_DESKTOP_COST]
 [TOTAL_WALKOUT_COST]
 STATUS

SQL> select value from table(split_clob());
 SRC_Copay
 3124332
 11423.1
 5477.93
 New Sundry Request
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost succeeding, why stop here?

```sql
with tab1 as (
select ' TaskType: SRC_Copay,
 [BILLING_ACCOUNT_NUMBER]: 3124332,
 [TOTAL_DESKTOP_COST]: 11423.1,
 [TOTAL_WALKOUT_COST]: 5477.93,
 STATUS: New Sundry Request,' str
  from dual
)
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(t1.str, '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^:]+', 1, 1),
       regexp_substr(regexp_substr(t1.str, '[^,]+', 1, level), '[^:]+', 1, 2)
  from tab1 t1
connect by level < regexp_count(t1.str, ',') + 1
```

Comment: Hi Nayi, Thank you so much for helping. But the column which has this data is a CLOB column. Will regexp_count work on a CLOB data type column? I tried running the query on actual data , but its loading for very long. Neither giving error nor output. Just loading for more than 20 mins. Provided the data isnt very huge. Its less than 4000 characters

Comment: Do not execute my statement directly, because I did not write a complete recursive condition, even if you only have 100 data, you cannot find out the result.You also need to add this  `and prior rowid = rowid and prior sys_guid() is not null`

Comment: @Akash, the string is greater than 4000 chars ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez no, lesser than that but it is stored in a CLOB datatype column.

Comment: and you want it in PLSQL or you want it in a SQL query ?